# How to watch for state/UI changes in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch

is there a way I can watch for a state change in the UI?

For example, in my data component I have a variable called `loggedIn`. If the value of `loggedIn` is equal to false, I want my header to display a `Login` link. Likewise, if the value of `loggedIn` is equal to true, I want my header to display a `Logout` link. So far I have tried:

```
<li v-if="loggedIn"><a v-link="{ path: 'login' }" v-on:click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
<li v-else><a v-link="{ path: 'login' }">Login</a></li>


data: function () {

    return {
      loggedIn: this.isLoggedIn() //this method returns true/false
    }

},
```

The code as is has the desired effect. However, it only works if my component is refreshed. I would like `Login/Logout` to render accordingly when the value of `loggedIn` changes... Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing the details of `isLoggedIn` function...

Comment: You're executing `isLoggedIn` once, when you initialize `data.loggedIn`. You need to have something that changes `loggedIn` at some point.

Comment: gotcha.. I thought that the `v-if` and `v-else` are reactive to `loggedIn`'s value changing..

Comment: @user1547174 `v-if` and `v-else` *are* reactive to `loggedIn`'s value changing. The problem is that it doesn't change. You haven't *bound* it to `this.isLoggedIn`, you've just initialized it. You might want to make `isLoggedIn` a `computed`, and have `v-if` and `v-else` bound to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** I just realized that `this.isLoggedIn` is a method in your component, and not outside it. It looks like you should make `isLoggedIn` a [`computed`](http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html) and use that in your directives.

Yes, *you* can watch for a state change in the UI, but Vue cannot. Vue does not know that the UI as a whole exists. It only knows about the pieces you tell it about (usually via directives).

In your example code, you initialize `loggedIn` to the output of a function, but after being initialized, its value is never changed. There is no [`$watch`](https://vuejs.org/api/#watch) for things that are outside the ViewModel.

Presumably, there is some login process in which the UI state changes. Since the purpose of the ViewModel is to model the application, you should implement that
login process as a `method` in your ViewModel. Among the things it will do is change the value of the `loggedIn` variable. As a general rule, UI state should be represented by `data` members, and anything that changes UI state should be implemented as a `method`.

It may be that logging in happens up the parent tree from this component. In that case, `loggedIn` should come in as a [`prop`](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props).